# Julia Markdown - how to execute Code inline

Tags: julia, markdown

I have Markdown code in Julia and I want to include the result of some code. The [Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Markdown/) explains how to do that in a code block...

````
```julia
some code
```
````

...but it doesn't tell how to do it inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://weavejl.mpastell.com/v0.9/usage/) of `Weave.jl` you can do

```
`j juliacode`
```

or

```
! juliacode
```

with the latter executing the whole line after `!`.